# Why is it not possible to access elements via JS on this site?

Tags: javascript

The website I'm talking about: https://sephir.ch/vfi/user/lernendenportal/index.cfm

I wanted to make a simple bookmarklet which fills my email and password into those two textboxes. My JS code works on any other site, but not on this one.

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name="email" size="40" maxlength="60" class="tdschwarz" autocomplete="off">
```

JS:

```
 javascript:function fill() {alert(document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value);} fill();
```

Error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Do you guys have any ideas why it doesn't work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the email field is within a frame, so the `document` object is not the same of the field's.

In order to access to that field, first you must obtain the document object it belongs to. Inspecting the DOM, you have to access to the `#mainFrame` frame:

```
var frame = document.getElementsByName("mainFrame")[0];
```

Now you can get the element:

```
var email = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByName("email")[0];
```

This works in modern browsers. In IE8 and older, there's this nice `document.frames` property that can make things easier:

```
var email = document.frames.mainFrame.document.getElementsByName("email")[0];
```

Comment: @dislick Don't feel stupid. It's a common oversight when it comes to framed sites. Nobody really expects them anymore (except, maybe, for Google web apps), exspecially when they don't look like it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Get it with `window.mainFrame.document`:

```
javascript:function fill() {alert(window.mainFrame.document.forms['login'].email.value);} fill();
```

Answer (score 1):

The input is in the iframe. You need first get the iframe and then get the input element.

```
document.getElementsByName('mainFrame')[0].contentDocument.getElementsByName('email')[0]
```